# Production environment use script tag in head section of website but not in Staging Environment

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have added an external script tag to the  section of a website - I want to use that just for production environment and remove it from testing(staging) environment.
Application is built using React. I am using Google cloud Platform for deploying built docker image and I am using docker-compose file for running multiple container.

How can this script can be used removed from staging and not from production?

```
<head>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    (function(){var g=function(p,q,t,v){
    this.get=function(a){for(var a=a+"=",c=document.cookie.split(";"),b=0,p=c.length;b<p;b++){for(var d=c[b];" "==d.charAt(0);)d=d.substring(1,d.length);if(0==d.indexOf(a))return d.substring(a.length,d.length)}return null};
    this.set=function(a,c){var b="",b=new Date;b.setTime(b.getTime()+6048E5);b="; 
    try{(new g(100,"r","abcd","https://abcd.siteinterpret.com")).start()}catch(i){}})();
    </script>
    <div id='abcd'><!--DO NOT REMOVE-CONTENTS PLACED HERE--></div>
</head>
```

Can I use some condition inside code?

```
<head>
<% if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production')  %>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    (function(){var g=function(p,q,t,v){
    this.set=function(a,c){var b="",b=new Date;b.setTime(b.getTime()+6048E5);b="; };
    try{(new g(100,"r","abcd","https://abcd.siteinterpret.com")).start()}catch(i){}})();
    </script>
    <div id='abcd'><!--DO NOT REMOVE-CONTENTS PLACED HERE--></div>
</head>
```

Comment: This depends on many things in your setup and there are many different ways of doing it. Can you edit the JavaScript easily? Also, how do you build your deployed versions?

Comment: How can I edit the JavaScript? Can I do something like just add if condition mentioned above?@JoelPeltonen

Comment: Editing the JS depends on your build system. If you are able to edit the actual JS file you _can_ make a condition to check the URL, but I'm asking if you are able to actually change that code; it looks like minified code from a build system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments; one option is to check the current hostname (assuming it's different for different environments)

```
<script>
if (location.host !== "testingserver.com") {
    // other code
}
</script>
```